# Folium marker offset to change the location of the point to slightly right

Tags: python, folium

I have a map that looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QQ2W.png)

Here is my code:

```
folium.RegularPolygonMarker([data["latitude"], data["longitude"]],number_of_sides=4, rotation=45, radius=12, popup=data["airport"],       # rouge
fill_opacity=1,
fill = True,
fill_color=color,
edge_width='1',
color = 'black',
tooltip=data['airport']).add_to(map1)
```

This creates the box that changes colors based on certian conditions.

This code creates the letters that go over the box.

```
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(
             location=[data['latitude'], data['longitude']],
             popup=popup,
             icon=folium.DivIcon(html=f"""<div style="font-family: calibri; color: #ECF0F1 ; font-weight:    bold ; font-size: 8px  ">{data['airport']}</div>""")
                  ))
    
map1.add_child(fg)
```

What I want is the letters to be slighly offset to just being to the right of the box.  **Is there any way I can offset the text to the left of the polygon? **

I tried just adjusting the coordinates but they still look to be on top of each other zoomed out but zoomed in the text and box are way off since the coordinates of the markers changes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your layout it is perhaps possible to make use of options for the `<div>` tag. Have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp and try to change the values for margin or padding like shown in the example